# Divide/split the array based on the value suming up to a set value and its relevant element to be grouped inside the splited array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

With an array like the one below is there a way so I can divide/split the array based on the value suming up to a set value. e.g if I wanted them to  less than equal 250,also its relevant element to be grouped inside the splited array.

```
Example

Array
(

    [42] => 10
    [55] => 20
    [56] => 10
    [57] => 4
    [58] => 5
    [59] => 240

)
```

The Output should be as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            ['value'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 10
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 5
                ),

            ['element'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 42
                    [1] => 55
                    [2] => 56
                    [3] => 57
                    [4] => 58
                ),

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           ['value'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 240

                ),

            ['element'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 59
                ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What happens if key 60 has value 11? Is it included in the first group or will it start a third group?

Comment: please explain the logic . Unable to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop the array and keep track of the sum.
When it goes above 250 reset the sum counter and start a new subarray.

```
$arr = Array(
    42 => 10,
    55 => 20,
    56 => 10,
    57 => 4,
    58 => 5,
    59 => 240
);

// Can we do all in one subarray?
if(array_sum($arr) >= 250){
//No
    $sum = 0;
    $index = 0;
    $result[$index] =[];
    //Loop the array and keep the sum in memory
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        if($sum + $val < 250){
            //Less than 250, just keep adding the values
            $result[$index]['values'][] =  $val;
            $result[$index]['elements'][] = $key;
            $sum += $val;
        }else{
            // More than 250, create a new subarray and reset sum
            $sum = $val;
            $index++;
            $result[$index] = ['values' => [$val], 'elements' => [$key]];
        }
    }
}else{
//Yes, group the values and keys
    $result = [['values' => array_values($arr), 'elements' => array_keys($arr)]];
}

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/jSdsA

Comment: Hi ,

For each subarray the sum total should be 250.


$arr = Array(
    42 => 10,
    55 => 20,
    56 => 10,
    57 => 4,
    58 => 5,
    59 => 240,
    60 => 123,
);

In this case its not working.

Comment: But in your expected output it's not.

Comment: @ImmaculateXavier see edit now. I made a mistake with resetting the sum

Comment: @ImmaculateXavier No problem, feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Hi Andreas, how to display the output in a table format

Comment: @ImmaculateXavier that is a different question. Different questions should be posted in different questions. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you. You do that by clicking the tick mark next to the answer. That makes it visible for everyone that this question is solved.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thanks the answer was helpful, and it was as per my expectation.